# how to remove in JavaFx from nested ActionListeners a specific actionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, overriding, actionlistener

Im trying to make painting Program in Java Fx
the problem that im confronting here is that,
i want to make nested setOnMousePressed Events and remove specific one for example
i ve found out that people use ,setOnMousePressed(null) but this effect both the first and second Method

```
canvas.setOnMousePressed(a -> { // first 
    
        System.out.println("A");
        
        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> { // second 
            
            System.out.println("B");
            
            canvas.setOnMousePressed(null); // i would like this Method to take Action only on the second setOnMousePressed() Method
        }); 
        
        System.out.println("C");
    
        
    
    });
```

Comment: Better option would be to have some sort of state (e.g. a `boolean` or something) that the handler uses to only execute certain logic at certain times.

Comment: make sure your understand the details of installing handlers (setOnXX vs. addXX), the javafx tag wiki has references to appropriate tutorials

Comment: @Slaw ok i appreciate your answer, i thought there would be some kinda function, that will determine which ActionListener the user wants to stop

Comment: @kleopatra ok i will thanx